# Angular ui tab with seperate controllers for each tab

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like to make a bootstrap tabset with each tab having it's own controller. Can anyone point me in which direction I should go.

Currently I have made several difference controllers, which I would like to be used in a tabset instead of having them displayed as a different route.

I know I could fake it by having the tabset in the difference controller templates displaying the given controllers tab as active, but I would like to be able to have a main TabController with several child controllers (for each tab)

Comment: Please insert your code what you have done??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using angular ui router you can use nested states to do this.

- Create an abstract state with a view that contains the tabs and a nested ui-view
- Create a child state for each of your tabs, each inheriting from the abstract state
- Each child state can set the content of the nested ui-view, and define a controller

  ```
   $stateProvider.state( 'tabs', {
      abstract: true,
          url: 'tabs',
          views: {
            "tabs": {
              controller: 'TabsCtrl',
              templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
            }
          }
        })
        .state('tabs.tab1', {
            url: '',  //make this the default tab
            views: {
            "tabContent": {
              controller: 'Tab1Ctrl',
              templateUrl: 'tab1.html'
            }
          }
        })
        .state('tabs.tab2', {
            url: '/tab2',
            views: {
            "tabContent": {
              controller: 'Tab2Ctrl',
              templateUrl: 'tab2.html'
            }
          }
        });
  ```

Comment: Adding the html would help those not very familiar with the framework

Comment: html would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put a directive on each tab that has it's own controller? If you are using 1.x. Separate your code out by directive not tabs